# Exception thrown: when converting a string to DateTime parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub btnOpen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpen.Click

' Get the date that the Order Date displays
Dim tmeToday As DateTime = Me.dtpOrderDate.Value        
Dim day As Integer = tmeToday.Day        
Dim month As Integer = tmeToday.Month        
Dim year As Integer = tmeToday.Year        
Dim strMonth() As String = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", _
                                "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", _
                                "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"}        
Dim strFilename As String = CStr(day) & strMonth(month - 1) & _
                  CStr(year) & ".xml"


' If the file exists already, open it        
If File.Exists(strFilename) Then            
' Empty the local data set of any data. This is required if            
' we want the user to be able to open different daily sets of repairs            
Me.dsWorkorders.Clear()

' Open the set of orders placed on the day selected

 dsWorkorders.ReadXml(strFilename)
```

Here is the error (the error comes on the last line): 
    when converting a string to DateTime parse the string to take the date before putting     each variable into the DateTime object

```
<Workorder>
<CustomerName>Jonathan</CustomerName>
<Address>gdfsg</Address>
<City>ga</City>
<State>gas</State>
<ZipCode>gaf</ZipCode>
<Make>gadfs</Make>
<Model>ags</Model>
<CarYear>gfad</CarYear>
<Problem>gfasd</Problem>
<PartName1>gfdag</PartName1>
<UnitPrice1>123</UnitPrice1>
<Quantity1>4</Quantity1>
<SubTotal1>492</SubTotal1>
<PartName2 />
<UnitPrice2>0</UnitPrice2>
<Quantity2>0</Quantity2>
<SubTotal2>0</SubTotal2>
<PartName3 />
<UnitPrice3>0</UnitPrice3>
<Quantity3>0</Quantity3>
<SubTotal3>0</SubTotal3>
<PartName4 />
<UnitPrice4>0</UnitPrice4>
<Quantity4>0</Quantity4>
<SubTotal4>0</SubTotal4>
<PartName5 />
<UnitPrice5>0</UnitPrice5>
<Quantity5>0</Quantity5>
<SubTotal5>0</SubTotal5>
<JobPerformed1 />
<JobPrice1>0</JobPrice1>
<JobPerformed2 />
<JobPrice2>0</JobPrice2>
<JobPerformed3 />
<JobPrice3>0</JobPrice3>
<JobPerformed4 />
<JobPrice4>0</JobPrice4>
<JobPerformed5 />
<JobPrice5>0</JobPrice5>
<TotalParts>492</TotalParts>
<TotalLabor>0</TotalLabor>
<TaxRate>7.75</TaxRate>
<TaxAmount>0</TaxAmount>
<TotalOrder>492</TotalOrder>
<Recommendations />
```

theres a sample xml file data

Comment: That's not an original .NET error message. What error do you get and where?

Comment: Check how the date time format appears in your XML file. It has to be in a proper format to be loaded in the datatable.

Comment: 26Sep2013.xml that's how the date is formatted as the file

Comment: I menat inside the XML file, could you provide a sample of the XML file content? I assume you have a date field in there.

Comment: I see no data for a date column here. I see that <CarYear>gfad</CarYear> is strange (I expect that to be numeric), but that is not it. My only guess would be that you have a date column in your datatable that is mandatory and that date does not appear in the XML file. Carefully check the columns you have in the datatable inside the dataset dsWorkorders.

Comment: I think the error really is pointing to the strFileName. the strFileName is like this: 26Sep2013.xml is that a valid string? or do I need to convert it or something?

Comment: The file name is just a string. If the file resides on disk with this name it must be a valid name. The error message says " when converting a string to DateTime"...This is not associated with the file name, it has to be either in the contents or in the datatable column definition some how. Would you care creating another table like: DataTable dt = new DataTable("mytable"); dt.ReadXML(strFilename); (oh it is in C#, please convert) If this works, then your datatable column definition is not compatible with the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

this code works fine

```
Private Sub btnOpen_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpen.Click

' Get the date that the Order Date displays
Dim tmeToday As DateTime = DateTime.Now        
Dim day As Integer = tmeToday.Day        
Dim month As Integer = tmeToday.Month        
Dim year As Integer = tmeToday.Year        
Dim strMonth() As String = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", _
                                "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", _
                                "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"}        
Dim strFilename As String = CStr(day) & strMonth(month - 1) & _
                  CStr(year) & ".xml"
```

so....the line below should be

```
CdateDim tmeToday As DateTime =  CDate(Me.dtpOrderDate.Value) 'otherwise its a string cant asign string to a date
```

and that is under the assumption that the dtp listed is not an actual datetimePicker as the DateTimePicker.Value returns a DateTime object.

Comment: I couldn't get that to work. Here's more info about the error: "input string was not in a correct format." It is referring to the dsWorkorders.ReadXml(strFilename) line. So something is wrong with the strFileName input